# VB 10 how to hundle multiple buttons

Tags: vb.net

I have made a form in VB10 with 50 buttons. How can i manage their visibility with a for loop ??
For example i want to do something like that:

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 50    
        Button(i).Visible = False    
    Next
```

How can i map the current number of the i? I want to avoid write it 50 times.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You should be able to iterate through the collection of controls.  If their type is button, then turn their visible to false.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the buttons no matter what container they are in, even multiple ones:

```
    Dim matches() As Control
    For i As Integer = 1 To 50
        matches = Me.Controls.Find("Button" & i, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is Button Then
            Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(matches(0), Button)
            btn.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If there names are Button1, Button2, etc then this will work:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 50    
    Me.Controls("Button" & i.ToString).Visible = False    
Next
```

Comment: This will only work if all the buttons are directly contained by the Form itself.  What if they are in a different container?  What if they are spread out over multiple containers?...